# How does node capture data from a form?

Tags: node.js, post, body-parser

relevant line from the ejs file:

```
<form action="/foo" method="post">
```

app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// I'm having trouble understanding this line
app.post('/foo', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

When we click on the submit button in the ejs file, the data is attached to the "/foo request object.

Does app.js have access to the request object because of calling this function `function(req, res)`? Somehow it seems to me that we are making a new request.

Also what is the purpose of the first parameter? that is, "app.post(*'/foo'* "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your app.js listening on port 3000

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.post('/foo', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
});

 //starting server
 app.listen('3000',function(){
 console.log("App started on port 3000.");
 });
```

Here you are storing the instance of express in express variable, it will have all the express functionality.
Now we start express by calling it's constructor,below line does that.

```
var app = express();
```

Here below, we are creating instance of [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) which helps us to read the request body in our node app.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Now we use body-parser in our app like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

In above line we are parsing request body in json format, so that we can access request body in json format.

Now app variable will listen on some port for example 3000, after that when user submits form, for example this form:

```
<form action="/foo" method="post">
```

For above form, when user submits, and in background we have already started our node app, it'll listen for '/foo' route through 'post' method, so the when '/foo' route with method post is hit, it'll go to its function body and run it:

```
app.post('/foo', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
        res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
}
```

In above function we are sending response back with username concatenated with a message,'username' we got from request body.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * POST request (when server receive a request from the client, normally used for 
 * inserting data into the storage system
 */

// app.post('foo', ...) is an endpoint whenever a server receives a request having '/foo' in the last e.g. http://localhost:3000/foo, the below function do some tasks

app.post('/foo', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) { // Route handler having /foo in the end of the URL
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

can achieve this in following steps

1. craete an object of the express module 
           `var app = express();`
2. create an instance of body-parser which helps us to read the request body in our node app.
   `var parser = require('body-parser')`
3. use the parser in our app 
   `app.use(bodyParser.json());` 
   here you will get the request body in json format
4. when user submits  form , our node app that is running in background listen for '/foo' route with post method .
   so when '/foo' route with method post is hit , it will go to it's function body and run it.
5. this function is sending the response back with username (we got from the request body ) with a  message .

next is : -- what is the purpose of   [app.post('/foo' "]
  when user submits form , our node app that is running in background listen for '/foo' route with post method(server gets a request having /foo ).
  so when '/foo' route with method post is hit , it will go to it's function body and run it.